# Wrong classpath in intellij for maven multi module project

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, junit4, persistence.xml

My maven multi module project:

```
root
root/core
root/persistence
root/service1
root/service2
```

`persistence` depends on `core` and `service1` and `service2` are depends on `persistence`. When I run `junit` test cases for `service1` or `service2` from `Intellij Idea`, class path used by intellij contains `persistence\src\main\resources` and `persistence\target\classes` which causes duplicate `persistence.xml` in my classpath. But when I run unit tests from command line using `mvn test` it works perfectly.